# "Zorn's Lemma guarantees that all algebraic frames are spatial." Why?

Tags: lattice-theory

In at least two papers ([here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~ual/papers/mar-zen-001.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~ual/papers/mar-zen-002.pdf)) Jorge Martínez and Eric R. Zenk say that Zorn's Lemma implies that all algebraic frames are spatial. However, I haven't been able to find an actual explanation or proof of this claim anywhere, nor can I think of one myself. Does anyone have an idea or a reference on proving this?

Comment: More generally (under AC) any continuous frame is spatial - see e. g. VII.4.3 in Johnstone's "Stone Spaces" (pp. 310-311)

Comment: I don't have access to that book out in the sticks unfortunately. Is there a sketch of the proof available online?

Comment: I am not aware of any. If you have access to "Continuous Lattices and Domains" by Gierz, Hofmann, Keimel, Lawson, Mislove and Scott, there on page 126 is Theorem I-4.25 stating that for any $x\not\leqslant y$ in a bounded complete algebraic domain there is a completely irreducible element $p$ with $x\not\leqslant p$ and $y\leqslant p$.

Comment: Every distributive continuous lattice is a spatial frame. See "The spectral theory of distributive continuous lattices", Karl H. Hofmann and Jimmie D. Lawson 1978.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be a complete lattice with top element $1$. Let ${\cal M}(L)$ be the collection of meet-irreducible elements of $L$.

Recall that a frame is said to be *spatial* if for all $x\in L$ with $x<1$ we have $x=\bigwedge\{z\in {\cal M}(L): z\geq x\}$.

> > **Lemma**: Every complete, algebraic lattice $L$ contains a meet-irreducible element that is stricly smaller than the top-element.

Proof. Let $0$ be the bottom element, and $1$ be the top element of $L$. Since $L$ is compact, $1$ is the join of all compact elements of $L$. Let $c>0$ be a compact element and set $$K = \{k\in L: c\not\leq k\}.$$ Clearly $0\in K$ and the join of any directed subset of $K$ is in $K$ since $c$ is compact. By Zorn's Lemma, $K$ contains a maximal element $m\in K$. By definition, any $x>m$ must contain $c$, so $m\vee c$ is the unique least element of $L$ that properly contains $m$, and so $m$ is meet-irreducible.

> > **Theorem**: If $L$ is complete, algebraic, then for all $x\in L$ with $x<1$ we have $x=\bigwedge\{z\in {\cal M}(L): z\geq x\}$.

Proof. Suppose $x < m:=\bigwedge\{z\in {\cal M}(L): z\geq x\}$. Then $[x,m]=\{a\in L: x\leq a \leq m\}$ is a complete algebraic lattice without meet-irreducible elements other than the top-element, contradicting the Lemma.